# Heat transfer with a small airgap - conduction v convection v radiation

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

I have a transducer approx 25mm dia x 25mm length which will sit inside a brass casing, but stood off from the walls by around 0.5mm. Obviously the brass is a far better conductor than the plastic of the transducer body. However, I need to equalize temperature between the two before the sensor is useful. Now, I *could* place it in contact with the brass but thermal expansion (which is greater for the plastic) may well cause problems with compression.

So, I have an air gap. The question is how much less efficient will the heat transfer be between the brass and plastic?

Comment: That's usually an application for a pliable thermally conducting material. What's wrong with using heat sink compound? It's cheap, it flows and it should last a long time.

Comment: @CuriousOne It has to sit in a number of different solvent vapors, ranging from hydrocarbons to organochlorine compounds. Everything is teflon coated (apart from the brass)

Comment: Ouch... in that case I would try to get the best possible thermal contact by using a spring mechanism (probably just a clip) that allows the sensor to move slightly against the metal, which should avoid mechanical stress but still allow for some thermal contact.